# How do I get options like group, subgroup in command line in java

Tags: java, azure, command-line

In Azure CLI, I see options like create/delete/update etc for resources. I want to implement the same in Java. Is there any library available for it?

```
$ az [ group ] [ subgroup ] [ command ] {parameters}

az sql -h

Group
    az sql: Manage Azure SQL Databases and Data Warehouses.

Subgroups:
    db          : Manage databases.
    dw          : Manage data warehouses.
    elastic-pool: Manage elastic pools.
    server      : Manage SQL servers.

Commands:
    list-usages : Gets all subscription usage metrics in a given location.
    show-usage  : Gets a subscription usage metric.
```

Currently I am using the following to create SQL server and SQL DWH.

```
java -jar build/libs/azure-mgmt-sql-1.0.jar -ACTION create -SUBSCRIPTION_ID <subscription.id> -TENANT_ID <tenant.id> -APP_CLIENT_ID <app.id> -APP_KEY <app.key> -RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME <existing.resourcegroup.name> -SQL_SERVER_NAME <sql.server.name> -SQL_SERVER_USERNAME <sql.server.username> -SQL_SERVER_PASSWORD <sql.server.password> -SQL_DATAWAREHOUSE_NAME <sql.dwh.name>
```

Is there a way to mention like below:-

```
java -jar build/libs/azure-mgmt-sql-1.0.jar create sql dw create <dwh.name> <existing.sqlservername> <subscription.id> <tenant.id> <app.id> <app.key>
```

Comment: Any updates now?

Comment: Refer my updated comment.

Answer (score 0):

This is the full azure SDK for java documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/java/api/overview/azure/

the part that you are looking for it is
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/java/api/overview/azure/sql

Comment: I am specifically looking how we can pass group, subgroup names in java. Its not fully related to azure. Azure is just an example

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the Azure CLI commands lines call the [Azure Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/). So, you could manage resources in Azure via [Azure Resource Management Java SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-java).

Please refer to the [samples](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-java/tree/master/azure-samples) to learn how to operate resources in java.